# Why would we need both EJBLocalObject and EJBLocalHome interfaces for a bean in EJB 2.0?

Tags: ejb

I am reading some ejb 2.0 text and I have read quite many such document so far, but still get confused why would we need both EJBLocalObject and EJBLocalHome interfaces for each bean.

For instance, I have a bean:

```
public abstract class Students implements EntityBean {
}
```

Then I definitely have

```
public interface StudentsLocal extends EJBLocalObject {
}
```

And

```
public interface StudentsLocalHome extends EJBLocalHome {
}
```

I know the role of each interface but still wondering what would happen if we did not have `EJBLocalHome` interface or something like that? Or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the client do in order to use a Local EJB? You go to the home and ask it for an instance. Without the home how are you proposing to get an instance?

There are also methods such as remove() which are on the Home not on the instance.

However, unless you are faced with maintaining legacy code you really don't want to do any of this - use EJB 3 and JPA: much much easier.

Comment: As I said, I know the role of the Home and Local. But what I meant is that why wouldn't we directly access the Local or Remore EJB. Why would we need another layer Home? Regarding the remove, in cause of entity bean, both Home and Local EJB object have remove() method. Incase of Local EJB, the remove() does not take parameter because it is known who should be removed. But in case of Home, the remove() take parameters to determine which bean instance should be removed. And this point confused me why both interfaces?

Comment: I assume that you accept that we need a creation Interface, that's got to be on the Home surely? By symmetry, it makes sense to me that having a remove there "fits". Whether it's absolutely "needed" is open to question, but having remove() on the Home gives some efficiency possibilities.